# Inlist the comments associated with objects in Greenplum Database

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

Is there any way to query and inlist all the comments associated with tables and their columns

Please reply back if you any query for this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Running Postgresql 9.4

Here's an example

```
CREATE TABLE test (
did     integer,
name    varchar(40)
);
```

Comments can be added at table creation  or using sql
Ref [Postgresql 9.4 Comment](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-comment.html)

```
COMMENT ON TABLE test IS 'This is a test table.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN test.did IS 'Description ID number';
COMMENT ON COLUMN test.name IS 'Description name varchar 20';
```

First of all we need to find the OID

```
SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'test' AND relkind = 'r';
```

IN my case the OID IS 24650

Ref [Postgresql 9.4 pg_class](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/catalog-pg-class.html)

table comment in this case

```
select pg_catalog.obj_description(24650);
```

(1st) Column  comment in this case

```
select pg_catalog.col_description(24650,1);
```

(2nd) Column  comment in this case

```
select pg_catalog.col_description(24650,2);
```